# Really Long Comment Wait Time?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please return the comment rate limit to a flat 30 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35501/please-return-the-comment-rate-limit-to-a-flat-30-seconds)
>   [If I can’t comment for 30 more seconds, why is the Add Comment button enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35443/if-i-cant-comment-for-30-more-seconds-why-is-the-add-comment-button-enabled)

So, I go to comment on someones answer, and then go to comment again on someone else's answer.  I get stopped by the comment timer thingy. I stop, I refresh the page a couple of times to check how long it is until I can comment again (looking at the time stamp of the old comment)

30 seconds come along, I try to comment. Doesn't work. I come back 15 seconds later, because I thought I might be off by a few seconds. Nope, still doesn't work.

Kept up like this for a minute. Then just decided that it wasn't worth it to comment.

Is this the intended purpose, to just make people so frustrated that they just don't comment? Or is it a bug in the system?

Comment: This isn't quite an **exact** duplicate; but that other thread should explain things... basically, it *used* to be that if you saw the message you had to wait a *few* more seconds. Now you need to wait *another* 30 seconds if you trip this message.

Comment: I realize that it resets .. the 'bug' was the 'frustration' caused by it reset an indefinite amount of times, meaning that if I didn't know any better, I could try to comment every 15 seconds for an entire hour, and the comment would never get posted. I think that THAT is the bug.

Comment: I apologize for sounding 'attacking', but the entire notion that I have to play a cat and mouse game to get my comment posted is obscene.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing. Simply that the existing thread would be a better place to discuss it ;-p And IMO yes, there is *at the minimum* a usability issue if it wasn't already obvious to you that it meant *another* 30 seconds.

Comment: @Chacha102: There are many, many of us who agree. Although I don't like to attack either, I try to stay level-headed, but it's extremely bad usability to have a sliding timer like that. I think, sadly, that the intent **is** to discourage the use of comments.

Comment: @Chacha102: other people complained about that indeed, on another question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35443/if-i-cant-comment-for-30-more-seconds-why-is-the-add-comment-button-enabled

Comment: Thanks @Gnoupi - I've added that link to the question.

Comment: @Marc I know you aren't disagreeing. I'm just stating that I was aware of the change :)

Comment: please come up with a better solution. This is really really really annoying and the resetting timer turns what should only be a quick 15 second wait into a 1minute+ wait and a mental disruption.

Comment: This is `status-completed`, but which of the two answers is the one that got implemented? The "accepted" one or the one downvoted into oblivion?

Comment: @romkyns The one that got downvoted into oblivion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree with the OP. I don't have a watch out in front of me, and don't feel like doing exponential backoff algorithms in my head. The new "timer reset" sucks.

If you (stackoverflow gods) want to prevent spammers / net traffic, have two timer thresholds:

- start the timer after a comment is posted.
- if someone attempts to post a comment before the timer reaches 5 seconds, complain and reset the timer.
- Otherwise, if someone attempts to post a comment before the timer reaches 25 seconds, complain (but DON'T reset the timer)
- After the timer reaches 25 seconds, accept the comment.

Comment: I'd make it like 15 seconds for the first timer. But yeah, something like that.

Comment: Do I hear 10 seconds? :-) If someone is just continuing to press "add comment" because they're waiting for the timer to run out, give them a break. sheesh.

Comment: I agree with your bullet points, but "I don't have a watch out in front of me" seriously? you're at a computer...

Comment: yes seriously. why the f--- do I have to go out of my way and play games with the StackOverflow engine? I should have to open up a clock application just so I can follow some artificial rules?

Answer (score -17):

Two modifications:

1. Message changed to be more clear

   > Only 1 comment allowed per {n} seconds; timer reset.
2. Multiple comment rate limiter reduced from 30 seconds to **15** seconds.

And like the 15 character requirement, yes, the intent is to discourage rampant adding of multiple low-value comments.

If it isn't worth 15 seconds of your time to compose that second comment, is it worth 2 seconds of my time to read them both?

Comment: Oddly enough, the main time I trip this is(/was) because I was having a comments to/fro on some specifics of an answer, and need(ed) to tell the poster that I had responded (so drop a comment on the question). With the new @reply feature I don't need this! So I don't expect to see that message very often. Happy customer.

Comment: I suggest "Only 1 comment or comment attempt allowed per" because when the timer is reset the comment is not posted.

Comment: Three more downvotes and you get the reversal-reversal badge.

Comment: @John This clearly should not apply to comment *attempts*, so I've made a bug post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-timer

Comment: @John ... and that's now fixed :)