# "Only 1 comment allowed per 25 seconds; timer reset."

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Really Long Comment Wait Time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35970/really-long-comment-wait-time)

I've never seen this wording before. Does this mean that if I press submit after 24 seconds the timer'll reset and I have to wait 25 more? If so, WTF?

Comment: I was looking for that. WTF? Duplicate. x10

Comment: WTF indeed, friend.