# "Only 1 comment allowed per 15 seconds; timer reset." is not working

Tags: discussion, comments, rate-limiting

When the popup

> "Only 1 comment allowed per 15 seconds; timer reset."

appears it is not living up to its claim. It does not allow me to comment after 15 secs.

Is it bug or feature?

Comment: @Tree: before I start voting on stuff, could you clarify whether you waited an _additional_ 15 secs after receiving that popup box?

Comment: Not that I don't care about the little people but I wish they slipped a little code in there so that mods don't have to suffer the same wait.  Because we're better than everybody else.

Comment: Please let me if i am wrong - Why in meta bug questions are taking as its always Wrong ... I am really not understand about it. 
Because every time i am seeing that none of bugs are replied back and saying that its bug.. Some people say "I don't care about the little people" ... Please fix the bug .. T hats y you are getting paid ... :-)  Rather than wasting time in giving  comment

Comment: @Tree, the full phrase was " __Not that__ I don't care about the little people" (emphasis mine); that's an offensive misquote.  (I used to be a journalist, so that really irks me.)  Also, nobody here is getting paid.

Comment: Stack overflow people are getting paid from ads ,... some one told me that ..  and i agreed with you ...

Comment: @Tree, it's true that SO, Inc. makes money from ads.  However, nobody participating in this conversation is part of SO, Inc.  Even Will, the moderator, is a volunteer.  (Almost forgot: please put "@[username]" in your replies so the system tells the person you're replying to that he has a message.  Otherwise your comment might never get read or replied back to.)

Answer (score 10):

As you can see it says "Timer reset". It means that when you see that message you have to wait **again** 15 seconds.

The reasons for that implementation are unknown, one of those "Jeff said so" things. It used to be 30 seconds and used to be **very** annoying.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37825/what-is-a-bad-feature-of-stack-overflow/37832#37832

Comment: It still IS very annoying.

Comment: It's intended to make you think twice about posting that comment -- whether that works or not, that's the intention

Comment: Your are answer is invalid :-)

Comment: @Tree - his answer is exactly correct. The behavior you are talking about is not a bug but a feature. You have to wait for 15 seconds. If you try again too soon, you have to wait another 15 seconds. Many of us don't like this, but Jeff Atwood is adamant about having it work this way.

Comment: -1 for "The reasons for that implementation are unknown"

Comment: @Popular: I wanted to say "The reasons for that implementation are absolutely dumb", but I didn't want to offend anyone

Comment: @Kop, I actually wouldn't have downvoted you for that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a dupe of: ["Only 1 comment allowed per 25 seconds; timer reset."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36121/only-1-comment-allowed-per-25-seconds-timer-reset)

Which is a dupe of: [Really Long Comment Wait Time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35970/really-long-comment-wait-time)

Which was deleted by Jeff Atwood.

Here is what it said, though:

> So, I go to comment on someones
>   answer, and then go to comment again
>   on someone else's answer. I get
>   stopped by the comment timer thingy. I
>   stop, I refresh the page a couple of
>   times to check how long it is until I
>   can comment again (looking at the time
>   stamp of the old comment)
>
> 30 seconds come along, I try to
>   comment. Doesn't work. I come back 15
>   seconds later, because I thought I
>   might be off by a few seconds. Nope,
>   still doesn't work.
>
> Kept up like this for a minute. Then
>   just decided that it wasn't worth it
>   to comment.
>
> Is this the intended purpose, to just
>   make people so frustrated that they
>   just don't comment? Or is it a bug in
>   the system?

And this was Jeff's answer:

> Two modifications:
>
> 1. Message changed to be more clear
>
>    > Only 1 comment allowed per {n} seconds; timer reset.
> 2. Multiple comment rate limiter reduced from 30 seconds to **25**
>      seconds.
>
> And like the 15 character requirement,
>   yes, the intent is to discourage
>   rampant adding of multiple low-value
>   comments.
>
> If it isn't worth 25 seconds of your
>   time to compose that second comment,
>   is it worth 2 seconds of my time to
>   read them both?

And it doesn't end there, of course. That question was a dupe of:
[If I can't comment for 30 more seconds, why is the Add Comment button enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35443/if-i-cant-comment-for-30-more-seconds-why-is-the-add-comment-button-enabled)

and

[Please return the comment rate limit to a flat 30 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35501/please-return-the-comment-rate-limit-to-a-flat-30-seconds)

Comment: 35970 is now active again.

Answer (score 2):

The timer is reset every time you see that message. So if you jump the gun by one second, you must wait another fifteen.

This is another one of many protections against spam-bots and malicious users. Basically, it prevents a bot from repeatedly trying to comment because it will continually have the timer reset. If the timer did not reset, then the spam-bot would just repeatedly post until it worked (once every 15 seconds).

Although I've run afoul it in the past, it's not too terrible of an imposition. Just use the extra 5 seconds to stretch your arms or look out the window.

Comment: +1 for looking out the window.

Comment: What's a window?

Comment: @mmyers, a window is a virtual area, often rectangular, that appears on your computer's display and contains the user interface of one program.  Check out the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_(computing)#

Comment: @Popular: Oh, yeah. In that case, yes, I do look at windows.

Comment: The timer reset feature really needs to be removed for users with enough rep.

Comment: @devinb: I don't think it's effective against spam bot. They just need to wait 20 seconds.

Comment: Those are the spam bots who get enough rep points to comment...