# User setting for Enter key submit-behavior

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, form-submit, options

> **Related:**
>   [Pressing Enter in comment box unexpectedly submits form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form)

Right now pressing Enter auto-submit comments and some other forms - but not others. When writing a technical answer you could need more than two lines of text f.ex. in a comment, and the good habit of pressing Enter to make a new paragraph comes into play... (and yes, currently paragraphs in comments aren't handled/rendered.)

Could you make it an option (ie. old/new behavior)? Right now it makes the Enter key a key to be afraid of, which isn't a good thing when you're composing text...

One alternative to option on/off could be to keep it on, but allowing the user to choose among a few key-combos (say, Enter, ctrl-Enter or alt-Enter) for the autosubmit function.

Comment: Duplicate?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form

Comment: The topic is the same, but his is not a feature-request. Mine is, and I suggest some solutions and wouldn't mind seeing others feedback on a solution rather than the problem. I'd like the thread re-opened, but wouldn't mind it being closed if I was offered some other way of influencing this problem so that it's fixed.

Comment: Reviewing the duplicate question, it would be clear that this behaviour is not going to be changed, reading some of the comments and answers, but I guess it's better to have a feature request status-declined.

Comment: Yet again, a *tiny* amount of explanation

Comment: +1 I generally like the feature, but it's screwing me over way too often.

Answer (score 4):

There is a stack app which can be used to emulate this functionality:

[Disable enter for submitting comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2061/disable-enter-for-submitting-comments)

It disables the auto-submit, and can be extended to toggle the behavior of the enter key.