# Comments are submitted when Enter key is pressed on a context menu item

Tags: bug, comments, firefox, keyboard

I use Firefox. Firefox has a spell checker. I use keyboard <kbd>Menu</kbd> key, select the underlined incorrect word, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to fix the misspelled word... my comment is submitted.

So I am forced to use the mouse to fix the spelling issues. Sometimes I forget it, and comment incomplete phrases.

So, the bug is **not about *removing* submit on Enter**, but make difference between a *context menu* <kbd>Enter</kbd> and an usual <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress.

Comment: dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form

Comment: @Martin Smith: and this is a *BUG declaration*, not a *support request* and in that thread there is not about the opening a (spelling) contextMenu, but about new lines.

Comment: Your "bug" is by design.  The explanation is in the dupe, which in turn links to the original issue where the behaviour was changed.

Comment: @Aarobot: see my update

Comment: Unless I'm confused about what you're doing, no repro in Chrome.

Comment: @rchern: 1) Do you use the *keyboard rightclick* on the misspelled word, select the correct one, and press keyboard Enter? 2) Use Firefox.

Comment: Ok this is really not reproductible in Google Chrome. This is a comment from Chrome.... OK, now I am back to Firefox, hovever.

Comment: @serhio Who uses Firefox anymore?...

Comment: @Chacha: he must have missed the memo.

Comment: Hey!  My mom uses firefox!

Comment: @Chacha @Andy People who hate Chrome perhaps?

Comment: @TheLQ Oh ... you mean people you hate progress... gotcha.

Comment: @Chacha102: for your information, Firefox is the most popular browser after IE, man

Comment: @serhio If everyone in the US called a Giraffe a Rhino, it would still be a Giraffe...

Comment: @Chacha102: I know that both Firefox and Chrome are browsers :))

Comment: @Tyler: except in the US, where it would be a Rhino.

Comment: Any chance you're on a Mac, @serhio?

Comment: I got lucky; my comment was ready apart from the spelling correction.

Answer (score 4):

Also confirmed in both Chrome (8.0.552.237, 9.0.597.84) and Safari (5.0.3) on a Mac.

Workaround for both: use Shift-Enter to make a choice.

(As an aside: both also catch Command-L while in the wmd editor. This normally would take me to the location bar but in the wmd editor invokes the "Insert link" option, for which I'd normally use Ctrl-L rather than Command-L as per the tooltip anyway. Not a problem, but it might help investigate.)

Comment: Excellent, this was driving me crazy.  At least there's a work around, but I'll have to get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this on Firefox 4.0b10.

A partial solution is to press the first letter of the desired correction; so press <kbd>I</kbd> for a correction of "information", for example. This will not work with the letters reserved for menu functions: U, P, A, S, and L.

Hope this helps!