# What should I do when a moderator deletes my post?

Tags: discussion, moderation

If a moderator deletes your post, what does it imply (assuming that no reason was given for the deletion)? Are you "in trouble"? For instance, if it seems to have been deleted inappropriately, is it fine to undelete it? And more generally, is it possible to get notification when your post is deleted?

[Background: [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form/70657#70657), which was deleted and is now locked.]

Comment: It means you need to include paragraphs

Comment: @random: But I did, in the post that was deleted. :-) Here, I intentionally kept the morbid detail of "background" together in one paragraph so it's easier to ignore. (That's not the main point of the question.)

Comment: @random: I've edited the question to shorten the huge paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

I found your post unnecessary and vitrolic in tone. Note that you had already answered the question once, and your position was duly noted, so adding *another even-more-shrill answer* isn't helping.

If you want to edit your existing answer, do that. In the meantime I have deleted and locked your answer.

I encourage you to seek out other sites on the internet if this one is not to your liking. Life is too short to be unhappy.

Comment: Thank you very much for a reply here! Now how about a reply there, so I can really believe "your position was duly noted"? These *sites* are very much to my liking; that's why I have contributed so much of my time — just look at some of my long answers on (say) Stack Overflow. But it's only your refusal to even acknowledge users' feedback that I find impossible to understand — can you at least justify your position on that design issue? That would be a GREAT help. (BTW, this comment got accidentally posted twice because of that bug, so I had to edit it.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, the deleted post had a reference to a problem on math.stackexchange.com: [Single comment split into many comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/787/single-comment-split-into-many-comments), apparently (if I understand correctly) due to people having the need to enter formulas in comments? Why not add that reference/explanation to the other post?

Comment: If a mod deletes it, then they've at least read it. They don't need to leave a comment on everything they read. Feedback was seen and duly noted, deleted. Your roast beef is with the delete. @shr

Comment: @random: No, my beef is with the actual design mistake (and the refusal to acknowledge or justify it). I don't care if my feedback is deleted or whatever, as long as the bug is fixed and we can use these websites more easily again.