# Cannot get to a new line by hitting Enter

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, user-interface

I am using a Mac machine.  I asked a question, and then, someone answered it.

I clicked `"Edit"` to add a comment, and I would like to press Enter to go to a new line, but doing so submitted my comment and ended the edit instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pressing Enter in comment box unexpectedly submits form](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form)

Comment: I assume you clicked "Add comment", not "Edit"?

Comment: I also assume [this is the comment in question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941547/cannot-find-system-runtime-serialization-json-in-monotouch/4946466#comment-5535350)?

Comment: Is it normal Mac behavior to edit a text field by pressing Enter?

Comment: I typed this first.

Then I hit shift+enter.

Again here.

Answer (score 9):

You can use <kbd>shfit</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to go to a new line in a comment, but either way it will remove new lines. This is by design.

For proof:

[image]

And after I submitted it:

[image]

And FYI, I clicked <kbd>enter</kbd> to submit it after I was done typing.

Comment: I couldn't find this in the help. Thanks!