# Suggestion for tweak to comment box "Press enter to add your comment"

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface

This is a suggestion regarding this [awesome new feature / evil UI bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form) (delete as appropriate).

Summary: pressing enter in the comment box submits the comment. This is not the intuitively expected behaviour for most people, but it does save a click or a keypress.

So, why not at least remind the user what pressing enter will do? Mock up:

[image: Add a prompt "Press enter to submit"]

Comment: I have the problem that I use exclusively the keyboard while writing a comment. I also use Firefox's spellchecker. But when I hit enter to conform the spelling, it fires off the comment... The submit on enter key is annoying.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. My suggestion: instead of putting the line below the text box, add it as hint of the box itself, so that it is even more likely to be read.

Comment: I would like to have this address to. I think I probably just did about 10 edits today because I accidentally hit the ENTER key. I often do it when I am replying to things because I like to "stand back" and re-read my paragraph. Hitting ENTER is my muscle memory doing this. Perhaps we could make ENTER pop-up a confirmation cover over the textbox where hitting ENTER again submits (so you do a double ENTER to submit?).