# Comment submission broken for comments that end with @username

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, autocomplete

Sometimes I want to post comments that include @-notifications but can't work the names into the comment text organically. In those cases, I write my comment out and then tack on a `@JohnDoe` at the end, which works just fine.

Well, it *did* work, until the otherwise-awesome new name autocompleter was introduced. Now I type out `@JohnD` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the whole name appears, but I can't submit the comment by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> anymore. The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key just does nothing. And actually, it doesn't matter if I tab-complete the name or not.

I don't think it's just me because it happens on multiple computers, although they're both running Win7 Pro and recent Firefoxes. Also, I would understand — but disagree — if this was considered "not a bug, just reword all your comments that end this way."

EDIT:
As the ever-intrepid pseudo-employee Tim Stone pointed out in the comments, what I initially reported is a special case of a more general problem: <kbd>Enter</kbd> submission of comments fails whenever the tab complete suggestions are being shown.

Comment: Since this won't happen if I reference @Pop (because he's the post owner and therefore not eligible for autocomplete), I'm posting a comment so that others can attempt to reproduce here.

Comment: Attempting to repro @Shog9

Comment: Repro failed, Enter still worked.  Chrome 14.0.835.186 beta-m / XP.

Comment: Another attempt on IE8/XP @Shog9. Success, Enter did not work. After submission, comment box also still contains my text instead of being reset to blank.

Comment: Ew. Trailing spaces are icky. But we'll see if it works. @Shog9 (EDIT: It does, and the trailing space is trimmed automatically.)

Comment: The problem is more generally that you can't submit a comment if the tab-complete suggestion is shown, by the way (which just happens to occur naturally when the `@mention` is at the end of the comment).

Comment: Attempt with Firefox 3.6 on Vista @Shog9 EDIT: works only with the space workaround - yuck.

Comment: Thanks @TimStone, I hadn't tested that! I reproed it with this comment, and will add it to the question now.

Comment: Tangentially related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form

Comment: Who the bloody hell drops names at the end of the comment? Tidy it up, guests are arriving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in September 27, 2016 as part of [upgrading the version of jQuery used by SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284996/we-have-updated-jquery-to-1-12-4-please-report-related-bugs-here). Enter now submits the comment even when the autocomplete suggestions are visible.

Answer (score 6):

**Work around:** After you've typed the name, hit <kbd>space</kbd>. Then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.