# We have updated jQuery to 1.12.4 - please report related bugs here

Tags: discussion, jquery

We have updated the jQuery version that Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange use from version 1.7.1 to 1.12.4 today (Tuesday, September 27, 2016). jQuery is an infrastructure library, and we've been running on an old version for a while because it worked well. However, there are a few improvements and features that made it compelling for us to upgrade, especially since some parts of the site already used a different version.

As a user of our Q&A sites, nothing should visibly change, as this is an infrastructure rather than a feature update. However, with an infrastructure update like this, there is always a chance for things to slip through the cracks.

> If you encounter functionality that used to work yesterday and is broken today, please **leave an answer on this thread** and accept my apologies in advance.

Please be aware of our [browser support matrix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).

Do **note that userscripts that rely on [deprecated jQuery functionality](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)** (like `.live()` - anything in the 1.7, 1.8, 1.9 and 1.10 category, and if you can in the 3.0 as well to make a future update less likely to break your script) may need to be updated. There were no DOM or other structural changes, so selectors should still be the same.

If you're curious why we're going to jQuery 1.12.4 and not 3.1, this is a matter of incrementally upgrading and making sure things work along the way. Pretty much every 1.x version had major changes, and jQuery recommends upgrading an old 1.x version to the latest 1.12.4 and [jquery-migrate 1.x](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/tree/1.x-stable/) plugin first and fix anything that is deprecated. We are in this stage now and want to make sure everything still works.

Comment: Should bug reports related to this change be reported here as answers, or as new questions? (i.e. what will have better chance to be noticed?)

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery

Comment: @ShadowWizard Once the update is live, I'll add a call to action to this post here to ask people to submit bugs as answers, although I'll be watching the new questions feed on Meta.SE and Meta.SO in any case.

Comment: So you're just going to [use jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)?

Comment: @Michael thanks, and just curious, what features of the new version are you going to use? Or will you leave this for us to find as pleasant surprise? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Mostly perf and browser compatibility, and some plugins that require a newer version. Better CSS3 support, better source map support, better typescript integration - no one "must have" feature, but 4 years of incremental bugfixes and improvements.

Comment: Awesome, thanks and good luck with fixing the bugs that ought to follow. :)

Comment: If the developers of SE write *minified vanilla JS backwards*, why would they need jQuery..?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up (and for the update)! Looks like SOUP *should* be fine (fingers crossed!), although I'll need to remove a couple of .andSelf()s in the next update.

Comment: @AwalGarg But it'll be newer jQuery now, so that we can add more with less effort :) We might even get basic arithmetic.

Comment: Just use `$.installJquery()` and you're done!

Comment: One step at a time.

Comment: You mean no more *"Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead."* and *"Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."* console warnings? jQuery just isn't the same without them. :(

Comment: You should update... 1.7 is definitely not enough jQuerys :)

Comment: [unrelated somehow] I wonder how much traffic burden is put on a site like SO, since it is erases the caches and makes the server almost send a fresh version of the script to many many users.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi If you're worried about sending out jQuery, it's ajax.googleapis.com that does that, as seen in the source code of this page.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi which depending on the sites you visit, you would may not even need to download it.

Comment: Hope that this will fix the [login problem with Microsoft Edge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306825/cannot-login-with-microsoft-edge-windows-10-browser)

Comment: @AwalGarg +1 because it is a lot of jQuery.

Comment: @ShadowWizard And we're live!

Comment: @Michael awesome, and surprisingly enough no bugs yet! ;-) Oh wait... first bug detected: Enter no longer submit comments.

Comment: @MichaelStum reminding you of [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284996/we-have-updated-jquery-to-1-12-4/285035?noredirect=1#comment924270_284996) - time to edit this to be a call for action. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Highlighted the CTA.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I almost posted on meta about the ENTER key not working on commenting, then just a few minutes ago, it started working for me again. Why that is, I haven't the faintest idea.

Comment: isn't 1.12 also an absurdly old version of jQuery? Would going to 2.0 not still be incremental enough? Seems like increments that small is just giving yourselves more work.

Comment: @TylerH Minimizing Headache. The big breaking version is jQuery 1.9 which removed all the old stuff. 2.x would also have worked, but then it would be a bigger question of "is stuff broken because of the deprecated functionality or because a browser is no longer supported?". Once the code is working on 1.9+, moving to 3.x should be relatively easy. We're [on Step 5 of the 3.0 upgrade guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/), so we'll skip over any 2.x headaches.

Comment: Developing for SE must be nice with so many tech savvy users to help you track down bugs :D

Comment: *".. and we've been running on an old version for a while because it worked well"* - Still, it might be a good idea to update sooner, stay up to date. Not just to get new features all the time, but also to have only small breakages, if any, which can be solved quickly, easily and mostly silently.

Comment: Want to engage in a scintillating discussion about Stack Overflow's quality assurance and testing methodology? [There's a chatroom for that!](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1042/discussion-on-question-by-michael-stum-we-have-updated-jquery-to-1-12-4-please) Join JonH and ArtOfCode in a friendly discussion of the pros and cons of flying by the seat of one's pants and landing on the soles of one's feet.

Comment: Will chat be updated, and if so, when? >_>

Comment: My "show accept rate" bookmarklet still works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166416/148233

Comment: So you ask us to do the testing work ? :-) Where is SO testing team?

Comment: @AvinashRaj we are SO testing team. ;)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Please see https://github.com/vyznev/soup/issues/27

Comment: It's been more than 6–8 weeks, so… are you going to fix the remaining bugs?

Answer (score 41):

> **This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)**

---

When you are on any page on any Stack Exchange site, when you focus on search bar, and then defocus(clicking below the search bar), it makes unintended animation of search bar and also along with badges and profile picture div:

> [image]

(Once, if you focus and unfocus again it doesn't happen.)

This is happening in all sites of Stack Exchange.

If you type something in search bar, then it doesn't happen.

If you need to reproduce it, you need to reload the page to see it in effect.

Comment: Also if you write something, then delete what you wrote and unfocus, the placeholder text is not displayed as it should.

Comment: Both are resolved now. That was some truly old functionality, incl. IE8 workarounds.

Comment: @Michael thanks, I'm pretty sure I noticed the placeholder issue before, but never bothered to report. The jumping textbox is the winner bug so far though... ;)

Answer (score 25):

> **This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)**

---

<kbd>Enter</kbd> key no longer submit a comment when pressed, as it used to do before.

Observed both when adding a comment and when editing a comment.

It does work on per-site metas, i.e. bug applies to all main sites. (including MSE)

Browser: Chrome latest stable (53), Windows 10.

Comment: Pushed a fix for this, should now work again on all sites and metas

Comment: Indeed, it does work again! What tab completion? In comments? It does work here.

Comment: Yes, I forgot our own rules about tab completion (1. Only list people in the comment thread, 2. Don't list yourself or the owner of the Q/A that's being commented on)

Comment: @Michael thanks, any juicy details why Enter didn't work? :)

Comment: The rules for the `:visible` selector have changed, or rather the order in which things are checked. Trying to figure out the exact differences and where else it might happen, but compare `jQuery.expr.filters.hidden` between [jQuery 1.7.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js) and [jQuery 1.12.4](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js)

Comment: @Michael thanks for the details! And on a side note, thanks for [fixing this other bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285038/152859), though probably only as a side effect! :-)

Answer (score 20):

> **This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)**

---

When adding a picture to a post, if I paste a URL, the "Add Picture" button never activates. Instead, I need to upload a copy of the picture (or manually enter Markdown to point at the external URL)

[image: In active add picture link]

Comment: Fix pushed, should work again now. (technical info: seems that `input[value!=""]` is no longer a valid selector)

Comment: @MichaelStum huh, got to love all those small yet breaking changes, that probably are not documented anywhere... ;)

Comment: @MichaelStum ShadowWizard [The API site says its still valid...](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

Comment: [It is indeed still valid](https://jsfiddle.net/3ze08t5e/)

Comment: I have issues with uploading images on [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) using Chrome in Windows 10. When clicking on "Drag and drop or click here" there is a lag of several seconds between the click and the Windows Explorer window opening. The Add Picture box is also greyed out and unusable.

Answer (score 18):

> **This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)**

---

It appears that moderators can no longer decline flags with a custom reason. When we go to decline a flag and choose the "other" option, no text box appears and we can't enter a reason:

[image]

I observed this on Safari 10.0 running on macOS Sierra (10.12), and another moderator reproduced it in Chrome. They stated that forcibly running

```
$("#dis_Other").toggle()
```

will bring back the text box.

Comment: workaround: stop declining flags. :) On a more serious note, does the similar feature to [reply to helpful flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223601/165773) work?

Comment: @gnat - The text box does show up for custom helpful flag acceptances, just not for the custom flag declines. We can only decline with the canned reasons at present.

Comment: This is resolved now.

Comment: @MichaelStum - Thanks for the quick turnaround. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Can we change this to status-intended? Stupid custom flags... for every good custom flag there's 10 that could have used a non-custom like word for word, I swear...

Answer (score 12):

> **This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)**

---

#### Searching for a badge to track progress on results in dozens of the same badge

As [reported on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335435/3853934) by **Sean Vieira**:

> #### Steps to replicate
>
> 1. Navigate to your profile
> 2. Click on the "Choose which tag badge to track" gear icon
> 3. Search for a tag name
>
> #### Expected results
>
> - The tag badges for the matching tag will be displayed (bronze, silver, and gold).
> - Only the tag badges matching the query will be shown (so for a perfect match, only three tag badges will be shown
>
> #### Actual result
>
> - The bronze badge is show dozens of times (see screenshot)
> - No silver or gold version of the badge is shown at all.
>
> [image: Searching for typescript in the "Select your next badge" popup, showing dozens of bronze typescript badges]

This seems to be related to the changes in the `.replaceWith()`, `.after()` and `.before()` methods. From [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

> Prior to jQuery 1.9, `.replaceWith()` would attempt to add or change nodes in the current jQuery set if the first node in the set was not connected to a document, and in those cases return a new jQuery set rather than the original set. The method might or might not have returned a new result depending on the number or connectedness of its arguments! As of jQuery 1.9, `.after()`, `.before()`, and `.replaceWith()` always return the original unmodified set. Attempting to use these methods on a node without a parent has no effect—that is, neither the set nor the nodes it contains are changed.

The bug is probably in the `replaceAvailableInDom` function in the the [`user.en.js` file](http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/js/user.en.js).

Comment: This should be fixed now. Interestingly, it didn't happen in Meta.

Answer (score 11):

When I hover over "delete" link ([link to example post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/332230/31260?noredirect=true)) popup doesn't tell me that I already voted.

Windows 10 / Firefox 49.0, Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m, Edge 38.14393.0.0.

<kbd>[image: example screen shot with missing you-voted part]</kbd>

---

Prior to change it did, see for example [Mouseover tooltip for delete count is wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233537/165773)

<kbd>[image: example old screen shot with present you-voted part]</kbd>

Comment: Not sure that this is related to the jQuery change. I have occasionally seen it not tell me that I'd voted to delete when I had. It didn't happen often enough for me to detect a pattern, however.

Comment: @AʟE. same here - prior to recent change it sometimes / infrequently missed but mostly was there. After the change it is 100% missing always

Comment: I think it happens right after you cast the vote, but after you reload it's fine. Can you please check it? (If that's the case, it's still a bug, but not related to the jQuery upgrade.)

Comment: reload doesn't help @ShadowWizard

Comment: It didn't show for me weeks after casting my del vote. However, I'm *almost* entirely certain that the behaviour predates the jquery change (last time I looked for things to delete vote was weeks ago, yet I remember this bug from then).

Comment: @AndrasDeak I use this feature every day and to me it broke only recently. It was somewhat unstable before though

Comment: similar complaint at MSO: [Why a vote to delete button doesn't show I already voted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335794/839601)

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is related, but it looks like fonts on error popups are missing and the browser falls back to the default font.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Checking. What browser are you using?

Comment: @MichaelStum Firefox. The first screenshot was also reproduced in Edge.

Comment: This is unrelated but a bug. `.message-text` has no font because it's usually set by a parent container, and in these cases there isn't one. (For reference, font should be `Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif` but no CSS rule matches here)

Comment: I winder if this is in some way related to tags losing some of their formatting randomly (seen on SO and MSO)

Comment: @MichaelStum should I report this in a separate question then?

Comment: @AndréBorie If you wouldn't mind, that would be awesome.

Comment: @Machavity Might that have been this issue? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285046/

Comment: @MichaelStum Yep, that's it

Comment: I'm curious. What do you have to do to get a "These profiles are the same" error popup?

Comment: @randal'thor on the contact form, ask to merge accounts. This will bring up two fields for the old and new profile, and validation actually checks whether they're the same.

Comment: @AndréBorie did you just stumble upon that or do you actually normally test such obscure things?

Comment: @AwalGarg for the first one I hovered my mouse over the dupehammer badge accidently. The second one I had to use the contact form. I usually don't bother testing anything unless I'm paid to do it.

Answer (score 10):

It appears as though the reputation graph is no longer accepting drag events, making it impossible to move about the graph:

[image]

Comment: What Site and Browser? it works fine on mine in Chrome 53.0.2785.116 on both Meta.SE and Stack Overflow and i've purged my cache from the beginning of time

Comment: I'm seeing it on Chrome 53.0.2785.116 as well on AskUbuntu. Let me try purging caches again (result: no difference).

Comment: I can't even drag the selection (i.e no visible selection at all). Chrome 53.0.2785.116 OS X, works fine on all other browsers.

Comment: Works fine also here: Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit), FF 47.0, IE11

Comment: Cannot repro either on any browser on Meta, SO and AskUbuntu, but I'll take a look at the code later to see if there's anything that looks problematic.

Comment: Works fine for me on AskUbuntu using Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 m (64 Bit, Windows).

Comment: Pretty sure this is not related to the new jQuery. This feature has worked intermittently (at best) for several months, at least for me. I actually think it never worked in the last 6 months. Right now it works here but it doesn't work on SO (Chrome 53.0.2785.116, 64 bit, on Windows 7, if that matters). And there should already be a bug report somewhere (either here or on Meta SO), though I can't find it now.

Comment: I was getting confused with [another issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259692/reputation-for-graph-is-off-by-a-day) about that graph. So it's possible there is no bug report yet, apart from this. But as I said, this has been around for a long time, so it doesn't depend on the new version of jQuery. Anyway, @Michael, if you want to look into it... Thanks!

Comment: Just realised (via [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285207/307988)), that my problem was zoom. All works fine (for me at least) at 100% :)

Comment: Holy crap, @Cai, you are right, it's the zoom! That's why sometimes it was working and sometimes not: because I'm using more than one pc, and more than one browser, with different zoom settings for different SE sites. And I thought it was "intermittent"! :-D

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the search box at the top of every page used to open the search results in a new tab. Now it does nothing (Chrome 53, Linux, no userscripts) or opens the search results in the same tab (Firefox 45.3, Linux, no userscripts). Since I haven't change anything on my end recently, I blame jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

When I do something that opens an editor, such as clicking on the “edit” button, pressing <kbd>e</kbd>, or clicking the 10ker “edit tags” button or pressing <kbd>t</kbd>, there's a long time (sometimes >1s) during which subsequent key pressed are interpreted as shortcuts, rather than typing in the text box. For example, quickly typing `t a` jumps to the answer box then opens the tag editor, instead of opening the tag editor and entering `a` there, which is what `t` <pause> `a` does.

This is with the official Stack Exchange keyboard shortcuts active.

I think, but I'm not completely sure, that this is actually a pre-existing bug (I guess it's doing something asynchronous to enter the editor), but I hardly ever saw the problem before, whereas it's been annoying me all evening today. So this may be a new bug, or it may be a new performance loss.

Comment: I'm also seeing this on Safari and Firefox, and I also have the impression that the bug was introduced around the same time as the jQuery upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

Every time I click on my custom tabs or go to the home page, Stack Overflow freezes the browser and then I get the following alert:

[image]

This is happening in

OS: Ubuntu 15.10 (64 bits)

Browser: Firefox 45.0

While in Chrome 49.0.2623.110

it just goes in a delay of 5~7 seconds while scrolling down / switching view of tabs

Already deleted recent history, cache and cookies

---

**EDIT**

I have tested it on Windows 10

Firefox version 50.0b1 (Beta version)

With the same results as above

Comment: With Custom Tabs, do you mean the new navigation? I'll try on Ubuntu in a bit, but it works fine in Firefox 49 for me :/ if you click "Debug Script", where does it break in the debugger?

Comment: @MichaelStum yes I mean the new navigation. It seems it's breaking on this method: `},"submitFormOnEnterPress":function(e){` in the `stub.en.js` file

Comment: Thanks, will investigate closer.

Comment: Same same, Chrome 54.0.2840.41 beta-m (64-bit) on Windows 8.1 - never had this issue before.

Comment: @MichaelStum Have you found anything? I have posted a separate, but possibly related, question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285633/ignored-tags-freeze-questions-page-on-chrome

Comment: @assylias from your own question I can say I also have a lot of ignored tags, so probably Michael Stum can get a hint from there, but I have them to be hidden, but the questions with tags on my favorite tags seem to load slow and freeze the browser until it finally paints them in "yellow/orange" in Stack Overflow at least, in other sites where I have no favorite / ignored tags there's no freeze at all

Comment: @MichaelStum is there any workaround for this error? Whenever I enter Stack Overflow I'm still getting the same error as above

Comment: @Frakcool I believe that I have found a potential cause of this, at least I could reproduce some slowness. I hope to have a performance improvement soon.

Comment: @MichaelStum thanks, it has something to do with ignored tags, I had about 100+ I think, once I deleted them I got this problem anymore

Comment: @MichaelStum I have added a bounty to [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285633/ignored-tags-freeze-questions-page-on-chrome)

Answer (score 4):

I visited [this post](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/27277/my-girlfriend-wants-to-disown-my-14-y-o-transgender-step-daughter) just now via hot network questions and although the sorting option was selected by votes, the posts were ordered incorrectly, and after clicking the "votes" again, they sorted properly. And right while I was writing this, there is 1 more answer posted. Don't know if that's all related but there you go.

Answer (score 4):

Tag suggestions are not working after the first tag.

1. Ask a question.
2. In the tag textbox, type the first letters of any tag. Observe that there is a tag suggestions popup.
3. Click on any tag to select the tag. Observe that the completed tag is auto-filled into the textbox.
4. Type the first letters of a second tag. Observe that there is a tag suggestions popup.
5. Click on any tag. Observe that auto-fill is no longer working.
6. Typing anything further in the textbox does not result in the tag suggestion popup.

If the question is posted then edited (thus opening the editing UI again), the second tag can be completed this way. However the third tag will not work in that instance of the edit question UI.

---

Problem encountered on:

Site: Aviation.SE

Browser: Internet Explorer 10

Comment: Will check on IE10 - it seems to be ok for me in Chrome and IE11, will bring up an IE10 machine now.

Comment: @MichaelStum with Edge and IE11 being latest versions, is IE10 still fully supported?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Edge and Internet Explorer are technically two different browsers, and we support two versions back. So we'll try to.

Comment: @MichaelStum Just FYI, you can run IE10 in IE11: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588769/forcing-ie-11-to-behave-as-ie-10

Comment: @Gruber from my own experience, I have found that running IE in emulated mode is not accurate on rare occasions. Generally it works though.

Comment: Can repro on IE10 (Windows 8) on Aviation. Works on SO. Checking for the root cause.

Comment: @MichaelStum Any update on this one? As of 1 Nov, this issue still exists. Also experienced a few other sites as well.

Comment: @kevin Sorry, was out for a while, I'll resume looking into stuff in this thread hopefully by next week.

Comment: Just a heads up, I found the cause of this, but are still looking for a solution (An event isn't bubbling under some circumstances caused by something completely different)

Answer (score 3):

Issues in the top nav reputation scroll (Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 64-bit, Mac OS X 10.11.6):

**1. Can't scroll using the grey rail**

[image]

**2. When you collapse reputation for specific day the scroll rail disappears**

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce this, using Chrome 53.0.2785.92 and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I also cannot repro using Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m (on Windows)

Comment: No repro either on Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

On the reputation tab in profile, if there is any reputation change since your last visit, the source from where you got the reputation shows up by DOWN arrow there, the bug is, it is showing two times the same sources if there is reputation gain from the same answer.

Once you reload the page, your reputation change since last visit becomes 0, and the bug can not be seen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711842/is-there-a-way-to-update-a-website-without-refreshing/39711861#39711861) was at -3 and was translucent.  I clicked the upvote and received a red box with a generic error (something of the order "There was an error.  Please try again.").  But my view of the answer showed -2, as if my upvote had been accepted.

So I refreshed the page and saw my upvote was not accepted and the answer was still at -3.  I clicked the upvote again and this time it worked.

Comment: Refresh the page and retry.

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg - ummm, I did.  That's in my post above.  But the bug is that I saw the error in the first place, not that it eventually worked after refresh.

Answer (score -1):

The reputation graph on the Activity tab does not handle the browser zoom properly on the latest Chrome on Windows.

If I set the zoom to 110%, and click on the graph, the blue area doesn't move at all, as if the clicks were ignored. If I set the zoom to 100%, it works fine.

Comment: Did that work before? I don't think it did.

Comment: Most likely it never "worked", since [zoom is not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274424/social-login-buttons-css-on-the-login-register-page-break-when-zoom-less-than-10#comment891801_274424). /cc @Patrick