# Tags shrink when loading a new edit via live refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, questions, live-refresh

After clicking on the banner to load a new edit to the question, the tags became tiny and awkward looking.

[image: Tiny tags!]

It seems that when the edit was loaded, they got wrapped into an additional `.edit-tags-wrapper` span which caused them to lose the proper stylings.

[image: Element inspection]

Comment: I pushed a fix for that, please let me know if it still happens.