# Missing font on some error and dupehammer info popups

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, error-message, dupehammer

Some popups like the dupehammer explanation popup or the validation error ones on the [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) do not have the right fonts - the browser has to fall back to a default and quite ugly font instead.

Interestingly, this does *not* happen for validation popups on posting a question - those remain fine.

Tested with both Firefox and Microsoft Edge.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like jQuery is to blame...

Comment: @PythonMaster [I'm not so sure...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284996/we-have-updated-jquery-to-1-12-4-please-report-related-bugs-here/285047?noredirect=1#comment924462_285047).

Answer (score 6):

The dupehammer message was getting attached to the *document* and not the body of the page - meaning that any styling on the body wasn't being used.

I have updated the script to attach to the body element directly.

With you in the next build.

---

Just saw that the issue is also on the contact us page - got a fix for that too, but that will go in in the build after next ;)

Answer (score 3):

The JS is appending the HTML of the message between `</body>` and `</html>`, causing it to lose part of the styling.

[image: screenshot of HTML]