# Ignored tags freeze "Questions" page on Chrome

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, ignored-tags

Since the jquery update back in October 16, the loading of the question page is very slow and freezes Chrome, sometimes for up to 15 seconds. For example when loading https://stackoverflow.com/questions

The content of the page loads immediately as usual but the formatting of my hidden tags is what seems to take some time and to freeze the page.

It may be related to the fact that, on my Stack Overflow profile settings, I have a lot of ignored tags.

> [image: screen shot of ignored tags]

Note:

- I have about 300 ignored tags
- When I go on other Stack Exchange sites where I have not ignored any tags, the pages load normally
- [This other bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285095/179508) may be related
- The page was loading normally before the update (i.e., in 1 second or so)

Comment: You have a lot of wildcards - these each expand to *multiple* tags.

Comment: Yes I do, but it has not created any issues in the past.

Comment: If you choose "Hide questions in your ignored tag", does it work fast?

Comment: Actually it doesn't, good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have been fixed...

Comment: Ah yes - the wildcards were the problem here. Marc put in a fix a few days ago. Details [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342980/questions-page-spends-6-seconds-scripting/343059#343059).