# Why is there a minimum time between two comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, rate-limiting

Sometime I need to leave something that will span more than one comments. But there seems to be a requirement of minimum time length between two comments, and the timer is reset if the requirement is not respected.

This is inconvenient, because the maximum number of characters requirement already cuts off my words, and the minimum in-between time adds another level of inconvenience, for both me posting my words and others to read and understand my meanings rather than my partial words.

Is there a more reasonable feature than this minimum in-between time requirement?

Answer (score 10):

> This is inconvenient, because the maximum number of characters requirement already cuts off my words, and the minimum in-between time adds another level of inconvenience, for both me posting my words and others to read and understand my meanings rather than my partial words.

Maybe the problem is elsewhere. If you need to post such big comments and need to expend them on many comments you should move the discussion to the chatrooms which are more appropriate.

Like Servy said, it is to prevent spam. There are not valid reason for this security check to be removed I mean it's 15 seconds we are talking about here not hours.

---

Edit: According to Shog9 it has nothing to do with spam. But it doesn't change my first point.

Comment: I hit this limit when multiple answers suffer from the same issue. These can't be moved to chat rooms. And moving them to the question doesn't really make sense either.

Comment: One problem with that is that finding the associated chat accounts is _real_ hard. I don't even think it's possible to manually invite someone without a pre-existing chat account. It's even worse with sub-20 accounts. And even if it were easier to find the associated accounts (I might write a userscript to do the lookup by name -> verify back link dance for me), it still feels cumbersome and unintuitive  at best. And yes, sub-20 accounts are a whole other bag of won't-works when it comes to your suggestion...

Comment: I mean, you post an answer and you get a downvote on it. Would you rather get a comment that was copy-pasted to all accounts, or get invited to chat? I guess naming the room appropriately helps, but still... Another issue is that such replies are invisible to random bypassers - who might be the real  targets of your comment. This has yet another unfortunate side effect if multiple people follow the same strategy on the same set of answers... lots of duplicate discussion, to say the least.

Comment: ... and there are people who let themselves to be invited into a chat room, then proceed to ignore whatever happens in that chat room and they keep talking in the comment thread right below the autogenerated message "let's move this conversation somewhere else".

Answer (score 3):

From my answer over on MSO: [Why does stack overflow reset the 15 seconds comment timer when attempting to make a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256817/why-does-stack-overflow-reset-the-15-seconds-comment-timer-when-attempting-to-ma/256821#256821)

> It is designed to be intentionally frustrating:
>
> > [That's nothing compared to the time collectively wasted by reading (multiple!) comments with less than 25 seconds of thought put into
> >     them.. write once, read many.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35443/if-i-cant-comment-for-30-more-seconds-why-is-the-add-comment-button-enabled/35450#comment78373_35450)
>
> The intent is *not* to prevent bots from flooding comments, but rather
>   to discourage *people* from posting multiple comments *period*.
>
> [There is some debate over whether this is a good
>   idea.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164048/please-make-the-multiple-comment-timer-less-annoying-non-resetting-etc)
>   By which I mean to say, everyone who has ever encountered it hates it
>   with a passion, while some of those who haven't don't care.
>
> Personally, I have mixed feelings about the timer; on the one hand, I
>   hate it when folks post multiple, back-to-back comments. On the other
>   hand, I like that seeing multiple, back-to-back comments provides me
>   with an indicator that this is probably someone who enjoys arguing
>   more than they do reading, which then frees me up to go do something
>   else rather than responding to them.
>
> [Note that moderators often have legitimate reasons to post multiple
>   comments quickly.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86784/lift-or-reduce-the-comment-rate-limiting-timer-for-moderators)

Comment: Could this limit at least be per-post instead of global? Quite often multiple answers suffer from the same issue (and nobody likes unexplained downvotes).

Comment: I like unexplained downvotes...

Answer (score -3):

Because spam.

Spam spam spam.

If you know of another way of mitigating spam in comments that's less intrusive to appropriate uses, you're more than welcome to suggest it here.

Comment: why still enforce spam measures on a user with certain reputation,

Comment: @Tim To prevent spam.  While there are many possibilities, the main reason for spam coming from a high rep account would be if it is compromised.

Comment: is it more important than letting others read complete rather than partial comments?

Comment: @Tim You mean you can't wait 15 seconds before posting another comment?  Your only option at that point is to give up and not post it instead of waiting?

Comment: during the 15 secs or more, the partial comment posted will cause misunderstanding.

Comment: @Tim It's extremely uncommon, and is not *extremely* confusing.  It's certainly far less disruptive than having a lot of spam flooding the site.

Comment: @Tim Also, you can leave a "[cont.]" (7 char) at the end of a comment, to indicate that you'll continue it in another comment.

Comment: Nothing to do with spam. Comment rate-limits were explicitly designed to discourage *people* from posting rapid-fire comments. For good or bad, that's the intention; spam-prevention in comments is mostly accomplished via [the reputation requirement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) - note that it doesn't exist on MSE, and we do occasionally get spam in comments here in spite of the rate-limiter.